# Loop through every property in Arrray of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, indexof

I have array of objects similar to this structure:

```
array = [
    {name: "Alex", content: "Lorem"},
    {name: "Bob", content: "Lorem"}
    ...
]
```

This array is mapped to the html table. I'm trying to build search method, which will compare each property of the object and return these, which contains word, which I'm looking for. I already have built method, which is working.

```
if(search_word){
    licenses = licenses.filter((item) => {
        if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search_word.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            return item;
        }
    })
}
```

It's working okay, but i need to specify each object property name one by one. I would like to have something more universal, where it will loop through all properties name. I have tried already with method:

```
for(let property in item)
```

But doesn't work for me. Can you advice something? Ah, i want to avoid jQuery.

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: how should look the result look like? do you want only the first found?

Comment: Now it returns item if it contains searched word in name property. I would like to search also in the content property. The point is, that i have much more properties, so i need some automatic method to search in every possible property of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `some` and `Object.keys` like this:

```
if(search_word){
    let l_search_word = search_word.toLowerCase(); 
    licenses = licenses.filter( item =>
        Object.keys(item).some( key => 
            item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(l_search_word) !== -1
        )
    )
}
```

Instead of `indexOf`, you could also use `includes`:

```
item[key].toLowerCase().includes(l_search_word)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. `item[key].toLowerCase is not a function`. Im getting this error, but probably i will solve it on my own :).

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution. The fastest one for sure. Only thing. Before using toLowerCase function its require to parse item[key] to the string `item[key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(l_search_word) !== -1`

Comment: `toString()` is necessary when `item[key]` is not a string. In your question it was suggested that they were strings. Anyway, be careful with `toString`, is it may lead to matches you are not interested in. For instance, if `item[key]` is an array, then `toString` will produce a string with commas, and if your search string has a comma, it may lead to a match you did not expect.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just stringify the complete object

```
if(search_word){
    licenses = licenses.filter((item) => {
        if(JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(search_word.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
            return item;
        }
    })
}
```

Will be time efficient if your object is large in size and also this way you will not need to check all the properties.

One thing which it will miss is that if someone search for `name` or `content` then everything will come up.

Comment: Works great! Ready out of the box :D. What is interesting, it search also in properties names, but not all of them :D.